# Can a PHP script wait for all variables to be updated from different Arduino's/users?

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I have three [Arduino MKR1000](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr1000)'s that have decibel-sensors attached to them. Every 5 seconds they send the sensor value to a PHP script, which puts it in a database.

The problem is that I need the PHP-script to wait for all three the values to be updated before inserting it into the database.

How can I store the values of the two Arduino's that update first, and when the last Arduino sends it's value it inserts all three values into the database?

My problem with this code is that the other variables reset to null when updating one variable.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

$db01 = $_GET['db01'];      //Decibel-sensor 1
$db02 = $_GET['db02'];      //Decibel-sensor 2
$db03 = $_GET['db03'];      //Decibel-sensor 3
```

I tried to return the script from this part until all values were set, but when one variable is changed the other ones are set to null.

```
if ($db01 == null || $db02 == null || $db03 == null){
        return;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO DDW (db_01, db_02, db_03)
        VALUES ('$db01', '$db02', '$db03');";

mysql_query($sql);
```

After successfully inserting the variables it should reset all variables to null, so it can start over filling in the variables.

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    $db01 = null;
    $db02 = null;
    $db03 = null;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Can't you turn it around: Have your script query the 3 sensors and store the data? That seems to make more sense as you will know that the 3 values belong together. And you should read up on sql injection and switch to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @cramopy Wow, this is quite a discouraging copy-pasted comment for such a well-written question(compared to most php questions).

Comment: @jeroen Hey Jeroen, thanks for the fast reaction. The Arduino's are not connected to each other, so they don't know when a value is sent. They only have a delay of 5 seconds in their code. The are connected to the same WiFi network, but I would not know how to let them "talk" to eachother.

SQL injection is not a problem for now because it is just a proof of concept, but I will keep it in mind for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should not bother with waiting.

Instead change your `DDW` table into something like that

```
--------------
|sensor|value|
```

And insert your data one by one

```
$sensor = $_GET['sensor'];
$value  = $_GET['value'];
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO DDW (sensor, value) VALUES (:sensor, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':sensor', $sensor);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can also add time of insert and ID into table if you need them.

And use meaningful variable and table names, if you ever want to return to this project, you will thank yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips!

I will send the sensor-index together with the value, and use the timestamp to pair the values so I have sets of 3 values per timeframe.

Comment: @TijnArts Index? If you mean "ID" (surrogate key), than it should not be sent from Arduino. instead, it should be generated serverside. Either as Uuid(good) or autoincrement database field(worse).

Comment: No I meant the number I give each sensor to identify it. It will probably look about the same you proposed:

| ID | sensor | value |  timestamp  |


Thanks for the help!